# Best Way to save data locally on the device in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, optimization

I am working on my first  iOS app which will be deployed for both iPhones and iPads. The app contains data that needs to be bundled with the app, which will be used when the device will be offline.

The offline version has atleast 35-40 records  with each record containing images(which would be bundled in the app, only names will be saved), and a `varchar` field which would be atleast 1000 words and a `boolean` field.

I have found three possible solution for the same

1. Save all the fields using database (`SQlite` or `Coredata`), however
   I am concerned about the table which will have 1000 words. But since
   the varchar field might vary, I need to allocate max 2000 (or more,depending on the actual length of keywords)
   limit (which will lead unnecessary allocation of memory resources)
2. Another Approach I would like to have is save the information in form of json locally and use it as and when required and save the boolean fields(only true locally in `NSUserDefaults`)
3. Use the JSON Approach as discussed above and create a database for managing the boolean fields.

I would like to seek the opinion of `StackOverflow` community on what would be ideal/optimized approach for this scenario. Also, I am open for any other approach as well.

**Edit 1**
Proposed provisional databased structure

```
Listing Table
id -> int (autoincrement)
name -> varchar(25)
imagename -> varchar(10)
desription -> varchar(2000)
favorite -> boolean
```

Comment: When you say: "the table which will have 1000 words", does it mean that you want to store 1000 words in one entry ?

Comment: @Laffen Please check the edit

Comment: SQLite doesn't really implement specific varchar data type, it is implemented as "TEXT": https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though the text field (with the 1000-2000 words) is static text that is bundled with the app and can not be changed by the user of the app. If that's the case, then you can store that data in the app bundle with plist files, or JSON files and load it on demand (assuming you don't need to search though it).

Then, if each of those records has only a single `boolean` value that is changeable by the user, those could be stored in `NSUserDefaults` very easily (since you've stated you're only dealing with 35-40 records). You'd use the `id` to link the `boolean` to the data file.

You could use `Core Data` or `Realm` to store the data, but it may be overkill if you don't need a search feature and the user can't change the text. But if you do go with a database option, be aware that you can not store static data (the text), in a location that is backed up by iCloud, or Apple will reject your app. Regardless of whether you use iCloud in the app or not. So if you were to create a `Core Data` persistent store and save it to the users `Documents` folder, then load in all the static data, you will be rejected. You would want to save that data store in the users `Cache` folder so that iCloud doesn't back it up. The issue you'll hit after that though is that you want the user's choices that are your `boolean` values backed up. This means they need to be stored in a different place. `Core Data` does have a feature that lets you create `Configurations` where it will separate the user changeable data from the non-changeable data, but again, that's overkill for your case.

I'd recommend starting with `Realm` over 'Core Data` for such a small dataset. It's much easier to get up and running.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to look into the fields, CoreData is th best approach, because you can easily access your data using `NSPredicates`, ( Like an SQL `where` statement` ).

But if you need to load everything at each launch, you can just store everything to a file ( plist, son ... ), because it is really more easy to managed, and to update ( If you update CoreData Model, the change may be complicated on the App update ).

So my short answer is :

> If you need to teach into your data => **Core Data**
>
> Else => **File on local Storage**

Do not use UserDefault to achieve that, this is not designed for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is depends on you data base's complexity and operation.

See, first thing is whatever data base system you used, there is no performance difference.

Every database system has different complexity and operation limitations.

For example, It is very simpler to use `NSUserDefaults` to store and retrieve data.

But if you required to do `relational operation` between bulk data then it is better to use `sqlite or core data`. `Relational database operations` are easily performed by `sqlite or coredata` compare to others.

There is another option is `property - list` also available if you data is only type of key value pair.

`Core data` is totally based on `sqlite`. In root core data itself using sqlite.

Difference between core data and sqlite is : core data provides more flexibility to use it but it is comparatively hard or complex to learn. Where sqlite not provide flexibility compare to core data but it is less complex to learn and use. Flexibility means for example : you can see visual representation of core data. Can visually add entity or attributes etc.

So, select data base as your need and complexity of use or base on operations that you will required to perform. Your database is not much big and not complex and not required any relational operations or multiple tables then you can use `user defaults or property list` also.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Pitching in with an option.

To make it easy for yourself later on, I would suggest using CoreData. This lets you easily manage the products for reading and writing. This also gives you a good persistent storage.

To the description issue; you could store the description for each product in its own file with a unique name that references the product you store in CoreData. In your CoreData entity you define a `descriptionFile`, which will hold the file path.

This approach makes it easier for CoreData when you fetch the objects, maybe you want a browse view where you don't need to display the description, therefore you don't need to load the description text into memory. When a product is selected, load the description file for that product and display the text within.

Happy Coding :)